# How to access redis connection in background task

Tags: python, flask, redis, python-rq

[image]

I'm trying to extend the flask-base project https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/tree/master/app which comes with a user model only. I'm trying to add the ability to run a background task on redis using rq. I've found https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq which is helpful.

this app has support for redis queues with a background redis queue being implemented by running :

```
@manager.command
def run_worker():
    """Initializes a slim rq task queue."""
    listen = ['default']
    conn = Redis(
        host=app.config['RQ_DEFAULT_HOST'],
        port=app.config['RQ_DEFAULT_PORT'],
        db=0,
        password=app.config['RQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD'])

    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

using:

```
$ python manage.py run_worker
```

In my views I have:

```
@main.route('/selected')
def background_selected():
    from rq import Queue
    from manage import run_worker.conn
    q = Queue(connection=conn)
    return q.enqueue(selected)
```

The problem is I don't know how to import the connection created in run_worker() into my view. I've tried variations of :

```
from manage import run_worker.conn
```

but I'm getting:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

How can I get access to the conn variable in the background task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the documentation, [python-rq Configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq#configuration)

Can you try by making the below changes:

**manager.py**

```
import redis

"""Initializes a slim rq task queue."""
listen = ['default']
conn = redis.Redis(host=app.config['RQ_DEFAULT_HOST'], 
                   port=app.config['RQ_DEFAULT_PORT'],
                   db=0,     
                   password=app.config['RQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD'])

@manager.command
def run_worker():
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

and from view:

```
from rq import Queue
from manage import conn

q = Queue(connection=conn)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't realize it before but there is a flask addon called flask-rq  (https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-RQ/) which provides a @job decorator to allow background tasks to be run.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the developer who provided the following:

[image]